# "Where" in the validation rule - Access VBA

Tags: vba, validation, where-clause, rule

Here is my problem: I have two tables. The first one is Stock_out, it contains a field named `Quantity_out`. The second one is stock, it contains a field named `Available_Quantity`. The two tables share a field named "RRN".

In the validation rule of `Quantity_out`, I want to make something like

```
[Quantity_out]>=[Stock].[Available_Quantity] where [RRN]=[Stock].[RRN]
```

The problem is where doesn't recognize "where".
My access version is 2016.
How can I make that?

Best regards,

SG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution from another website. It's working.

Hi,

it's not possible to reference a different table in a validation rule.

There are two methods if you want to apply such a rule at the table level:

1. with macro code in a Before Change data macro (in Access versions >=2010),
   example 4 in this article shows how to refer to a different table
2. in all versions >=Access 2000 you can use a CHECK constraint, which however has disadvantages:
   It can only be done by VBA+ADO and is not visible in the UI, and you (almost) can't configure the error message. Code for your requirements:
   CurrentProject.Connection.Execute _
   "ALTER TABLE Stock_out" & _
      " ADD CONSTRAINT Quantity_Must_Be_Higher_Or_Equal" & _
      "  CHECK (Stock_out.Quantity_out >= (SELECT Stock.Available_Quantity FROM Stock" & _
      "  WHERE Stock.RRN = Stock_out.RRN))"

The example uses the constraint name to give the user a hint what's wrong, as it is the only way to write sth into the system error message.

cu
Karl
[Access FAQ](http://donkarl.com) (de/it): donkarl.com
[Access Lobby](http://accessdevelopers.org): AccessDevelopers.org